# Remove grub2 core.img (having 2) and resize /boot/efi

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

Some time ago I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10.

I think I might have done some mistakes while installing Ubuntu.

I fact, I had to install it twice and I might have done bad things to my
partitions.

This is my current table:

[image: screenshot of GParted]

**My problems:**

**1.** Why do I have **two grub2 core.img** partitions? Can I remove one? The latter?

I have 5.62 GiB unallocated behind the second grub2 core.img and I would like
to merge them together with the freed space from the img into `0n1p6`, which will be my separate `/home`.

**2.** /boot/efi is too small, so I can't update my firmware

```
fwupdmgr -get-devices

XPS 13 9380 System Firmware
  DeviceId:             6c24a747f97668873b761558e322398a91dbf394
  Guid:                 ce945437-7358-49f1-95d8-6b694a10a755
  Plugin:               uefi
  Flags:                internal|require-ac|supported|registered|needs-reboot
  Version:              0.1.10.0
  VersionLowest:        0.1.10.0
  VersionFormat:        quad
  Icon:                 computer
  Created:              2020-04-26
  UpdateState:          success
  UpdateError:          /boot/efi does not have sufficient space, required 33,6 MB, got 25,7 MB
```

What would be a good solution to apply more space to `/boot/efi`?

Comment: If anything, what can I do to make my question better for you?

Comment: Ubuntu install on gpt partition requires either the 1MB unformatted bios_grub partition for BIOS boot. Or an ESP - efi system partition. Not sure how you got second bios_grub partition but too large. Was it something else and you changed parameters in gparted?  If now booting in UEFI mode you can delete both if second really is empty. I do use larger ESP for UEFI update but fwup does not work on my system. UEFI/BIOS updates brand model list  for Dell with (uefi >= 0.6.2 & dell >= 0.7.3) 
https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist
You can just create a larger FAT32 (not ESP) if really needed.

Comment: It's really long ago, but my guess is that it was my fault editing the partition sizes, while going through the ubuntu dual boot docs and not understanding all of it. I mounted both and they are not empty. I'll add a list of files they contain. // With just creating a larger FAT, you mean creating a new partition for /boot/efi and moving the files? I guess I'll need to write this change in some conf file, to make it work afterwards, do I?

Comment: Okay well, I could swear that I was able to mount them. Now it won't let me, because of this: sudo mount -t auto -v /dev/nvme0n1p8 /mnt/grubStuff/
mount: /mnt/grubStuff: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p8, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Comment: The bios_grub is unformatted and cannot be normally mounted. The grub2 core.img file is just the code in that unformatted partition. You cannot edit mounted partitions, little key icon shows mounted. You normally use Ubuntu live installer's gparted or a gparted live ISO. Windows typically makes ESP  100MB and that is normally large enough for several installs.